# Find non-match using regex (multiple lines)

Tags: regex, perl

I have a multi-line file from which I'm trying to find if the file has anything other than the regex string.

Ex:

```
test 1 str
test 2 str
unmatched string
```

Sample Regex:

```
/test .* str/
```

This regex returns true if it finds a match in the above data. However, I want it to return false at the first mismatch. Is that possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I don't have any ideas for the above question. Anything that I've so far returned true -- because everytime it matches a string my regex implementations didn't care about anything else. I'm not a regex expert either. I'm not looking for solved answers by any means, but suggestions, certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one uses `$string =~ /PATTERN/` to test if a `$string` matches a specific regex pattern.

However, one can also test for the negative, or not matching: `$string !~ /PATTERN/`.

In this case though, I think you can do it even simpler like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print if ! /test.*str/;
}

__DATA__
test 1 str
test 2 str
unmatched string
```

Outputs:

```
unmatched string
```

Comment: Awesome. Read about negative once in online doc but it didn't come to my mind until I read the answer. I implemented a similar expression for my use. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
while(<>)
{
    return 0 unless(/test .* str/);
}
return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little trick if you use a regex like this:

```
^test . str$|(.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jJ1sF3/1)**

Then grab the content of the capturing group. If the capturing group contains data then you assume that your file doesn't match your need.

[image]